# MSDeploy Fails with "Error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Tags: ssl, iis, webdeploy

Hello guys I'm struggling over here....

I'm unable to solve this problem no matter what I do.

I have two web servers both with IIS Management enabled, I run a build from my build server and then depending which environment it goes to the MS deploy URL changes but the command looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='E:\data\teamcity\BuildAgent\work\d9f8b686a8037f97\webdeploy_UAT\BuildCode_UAT.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="https://SERVER.DOMAIN.LOCAL:8172/MsDeploy.axd",userName="\username",password="******",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"E:\data\teamcity\BuildAgent\work\d9f8b686a8037f97\webdeploy_Review\BUILDCODE_UAT.SetParameters.xml"  -allowUntrusted
```

I've also created a sample command in my testing as well that doesn't work to the production web server either:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:dump -source:iisapp="Default Web Site",computername=https://SERVER.DOMAIN.local:8172/,authType=NTLM  -verbose -whatif -allowuntrusted
```

I understand this wouldn't actually do anything however, I would receive a different error than what I've been receiving:

```
Error: Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://SERVER.DOMAIN.local:8172/'.
Error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Error count: 1.
```

These commands generate feedback upon executing them against my dev server, that server works properly and I'm still able to deploy.

This process has been setup and working for years, however; over the weekend my infrastructure team did install windows updates and then when come Monday morning, we were no longer able to deploy to that server.

What I've done:

- Rolled back all of those updates
- Restored the VM prior to installing the updates
- Confirmed not network or firewall issue as I am able to telnet from the build server over port 8172 to the server in question...Also, I tried running the command on the server itself changing the URL to localhost and it still doesn't work
- Rebooted
- Ran a repair against .NET 4.7.2
- Ran a repair against Web deploy 3.0
- Regedits were in place to enable all TLS
- Ran a powershell script to dump TLS settings to confirm that I wasn't reading the regedits incorrectly
- Compared TLS settings with my dev server - all good
- Added SchUseStrongCrypto regedits on my build server - no change
- I'm unable to even receive any feedback other than "connection closed" When trying to hit the URL via a browser
- So finally, I installed fiddler on my computer; setup my connection in Web management console to allow my IP and tried to hit the URL while in fiddler and this is what I receive:

  HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
  FiddlerGateway: Direct
  StartTime: 13:30:10.019
  Connection: close
  fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to SERVER.DOMAIN.local (for #21) failed. System.IO.IOException
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
  remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
- To me, that suggested something was wrong with the SSL cert, I created a new self signed cert in IIS and applied the certificate via management console, still doesn't work!!

Help me!!!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What was updated when you installed windows updates? Your question is too complicated, I suggest you go to [microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection) for help.

Comment: 4.7.2 .NET KB updates.. And how is my question too complicated? Other people have asked this same question it's just I've outlined more troubleshooting steps than they have?